# Rollup - Re-export wildcard not working with default

Tags: typescript, rollup

I have a file `src/Button/Button.tsx`:

```
export default function Button(){}
export interface ButtonProps {}
```

I am re-exporting all the exports in a file `src/Button/index.ts`:

```
export * from './Button'; //i.e src/Button/Button.tsx
```

In my entry file I am re-exporting everything including this particular component:

```
export { ButtonProps, default as Button } from './Button'; //i.e src/Button/index.ts
```

When running a UMD build with rollup however, I get an error at the line above:

```
src/index.ts → dist/comp-framework.js...
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by src\Button\index.ts
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module-
src\index.ts (1:22)
1: export { ButtonProps, default as Button } from './Button';

Error: 'default' is not exported by src\Button\index.ts
```

This is strange since running just `tsc` works absolutely fine. So has to be an issue with rollup or the typescript plugin. My rollup config (I've removed all other plugins other than TS to narrow down the issue):

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

const input = 'src/index.ts';
const globals = {
  react: 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
};
const tsOverrides = {
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'es2015',
    declaration: false,
  }
};

export default [
  {
    input,
    output: {
      file: 'dist/comp-framework.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'CompFramework',
      globals
    },
    external: Object.keys(globals),
    plugins: [
      typescript({ typescript: require('typescript'), tsconfigOverride: tsOverrides, rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true }),
    ]
  },
  {
    input,
    output: {
      file: 'dist/comp-framework.min.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'CompFramework',
      globals
    },
    external: Object.keys(globals),
    plugins: [
      typescript({ typescript: require('typescript'), tsconfigOverride: tsOverrides, rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true }),
    ]
  }
]
```

EDIT: [example on the REPL](https://rollupjs.org/repl/?version=1.18.0&shareable=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)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually part of the language design - the `export * from 'x'` syntax is supposed to export everything except `default`.

If you check out the [GetExportedNames operation in the language standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-getexportednames), you can see the special logic to avoid the `default` entry in the StarExportEntries section.